# iOS - check if image is present in app bundle

Tags: ios, nsbundle, app-bundle

How can I tell if an image is present in the main app bundle based on a string? For example, is there an image called image1.png in the bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NSBundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method:

```
- (NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)extension
```

will return nil if no image was found.

i.e.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image1" ofType@"png"];
if(filePath.length > 0 && filePath != (id)[NSNull null]) {
   UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I get the image if I find it, since that method just returns a string?

Comment: [UIImage imageWithContentOfFile:yourFilePath];

Comment: The second comparison in the if statement is incorrect. Nil is not the same thing as [NSNull null], so the comparison doesn't make sense.